# Protractor custom Cucumber plugin giving error basedir=`dirname "$0"`

Tags: node.js, testing, cucumber, protractor, bdd

I have protractor and cucumber as global dependencies and I set NODE_PATH environmental variable, for my requirement i am needed to create custom plugin with some changes to cucumber.js in protractor with in my Project structure. I am getting below error when run new framework.js

Error :

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

C:\*****\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\cucumber.js:2
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.exports.run (D:\**********\*****\protractor\cucumber.js:13:18)
    at C:\*****\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:326:35
    at _fulfilled (C:\*****\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\*****\*****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

My custom plugin code is

```
var ConfigParser = require(process.argv[1]+'/../../lib/configParser'),
  q = require('q');

/**
 * Execute the Runner's test cases through Cucumber.
 *
 * @param {Runner} runner The current Protractor Runner.
 * @param {Array} specs Array of Directory Path Strings.
 * @return {q.Promise} Promise resolved with the test results
 */
exports.run = function(runner, specs) {
  // TODO - add the event interface for cucumber.
  var Cucumber = require('cucumber'), <-- getting error here
      execOptions = ['node', 'node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js'],
      cucumberResolvedRequire;
etc...
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong..

Thanks.